# Why are there no DOOM 2 Nightmare 100% kill speedruns?

Tags: speedrun, doom-2

I can't find any videos of a DOOM 2 speedrun on Nightmare difficulty with a 100% monster kill ratio?

I've seen:

- Ultra-violence, 100% Kills
- Nightmare, 100% secrets
- Nightmare, completion

Why can't I find any Nightmare speedruns that also have 100% kills?

Comment: Hi Kerk! Your original question as written was off-topic, since it was a "video recommendation" question. @Venoda and I have modified your question to instead be asking *why*  there aren't any speedruns of  DOOM 2 Nightmare 100% kill ratio. Are you fine with this change to your question?

Comment: sure no problem at all

Answer (score 56, accepted):

So one of the quirks of the Nightmare difficulty is that monsters respawn.

This means you can actually achieve more than 100% kills for a given level, making the distinction of 100% kills pretty pointless. Notably, enemies resurrected by Archviles (on all difficulty modes) also count towards your total kills and can similarly take you over the level's official enemy count to produce more than 100% of the kills.

This is why you sometimes see Ultra-Violence (or any non-Nightmare difficulty) speedruns with the tag 'fast monsters' since that's another really notable change of Nightmare. The fast monsters setting when combined with the Ultra-violence difficulty effectively creates a difficulty between Ultra-Violence and Nightmare that still lets a runner achieve 100% kills.

Here's some Doom speedrunning categories you might see in relation to all this (The names vary by site, but these are some common ones):

- UV Speed (Ultra-Violence)
- UV Max (Ultra-Violence, 100% Kills, 100% Secrets)
- UV Fast (Ultra-Violence, 100% Kills, 100% Secrets, Fast Monsters)
- NM Speed (Nightmare)
- NM100S (Nightmare, 100% Secrets)

For anyone interested in the details of the difficulty modes, I'd suggest you check [this video](https://youtu.be/af64p7GxQHU). The channel also has plenty of others that can help you understand the gritty details of how the DOOM engine and the games work.

Comment: The only difference between `-skill 4 -respawn -fast` is that `-skill 5` gives you double ammo from pick-ups, making UV with those parameters actually the hardest way to play the game. [Skill level](https://doom.fandom.com/wiki/Skill_level)

Comment: Someone the comments section of the video I linked claims "Enemies in Nightmare difficulty also have their minimum time before the first attack removed" but I haven't seen another source on it. Might need to independently verify it.

Comment: The lack of double ammo with respawn must be pretty hellish, yeesh. Strange that the hardest mode is technically on UV though.

Comment: also notice the LAST secret on level 15 was only debunked and solved ~3 years ago, rendering all previous 100% speedruns void